# External displays freezing

Tags: display

I have a Levono ThinkPad P16 Gen 1 with ubuntu 22.04 with two external monitors (both HDMI), every now and then both the monitors freeze and I can't use them until I reboot the laptop

I can still use the built-in monitor of the laptop and except for being frozen visually the OS acts as if the two external screens were still connected. If I disconnect and reconnect either of the displays the laptop screen goes black as well and I can't get it back without a reboot

Some times switching the primary monitor in display settings can fix the issue, but it's not reliable and in general changing display settings (e.g. moving screen configuration around) will some times trigger the freeze

Any ideas how to debug this issue? `xrandr -q` returns the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7040 x 1600, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 2560x1600+4480+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 215mm
   2560x1600     60.00*+  60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 connected 1920x1080+0+520 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   1920x1080     75.00*+  60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.95    59.94    59.93  
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 2560x1440+1920+160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+ 144.00   119.99  
   1920x1080    120.00   119.88    60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-1-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Last few lines of `sudo dmesg -T`:

```
[Do Mär  2 10:01:18 2023] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Idling display engine timed out: 0x0000c67e:0:0:1128
[Do Mär  2 10:01:20 2023] nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Idling display engine timed out: 0x0000c67e:2:0:1128
[Do Mär  2 10:01:23 2023] rfkill: input handler disabled
[Do Mär  2 10:01:24 2023] audit: type=1326 audit(1677747685.001:63): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=2957 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/638/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f76e9c4c73d code=0x50000
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1107 audit(1677747686.163:64): pid=905 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=2957 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=930 peer_label="unconfined"
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1420 audit(1677747686.163:65): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1107 audit(1677747686.163:66): pid=905 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=2957 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=930 peer_label="unconfined"
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1420 audit(1677747686.163:67): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1107 audit(1677747686.163:68): pid=905 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=2957 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=930 peer_label="unconfined"
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1420 audit(1677747686.163:69): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1107 audit(1677747686.163:70): pid=905 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.5" pid=2957 label="snap.snap-store.snap-store" peer_pid=930 peer_label="unconfined"
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1420 audit(1677747686.163:71): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[Do Mär  2 10:01:25 2023] audit: type=1400 audit(1677747686.445:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.snap-store" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=2957 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

and for `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    49.670] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:80
[    49.695] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    49.695] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:81
[    49.711] (WW) NVIDIA(G0): Failed to set the display configuration
[    49.711] (WW) NVIDIA(G0):  - Setting a mode on head 0 failed: Insufficient permissions
[    49.711] (WW) NVIDIA(G0):  - Setting a mode on head 1 failed: Insufficient permissions
[    49.711] (WW) NVIDIA(G0):  - Setting a mode on head 2 failed: Insufficient permissions
[    49.711] (WW) NVIDIA(G0):  - Setting a mode on head 3 failed: Insufficient permissions
[    49.716] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Deleting GPU-0
[    49.717] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Is there anything in the output of `sudo dmesg -T` around the time when the displays freeze? Is there anything in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` either? There may be GPU or CPU related error messages / crashes reported in either of those logs.

Comment: @popey added the last few lines of both to the original question, not sure if it's related but there are some errors in both

Comment: I'm asking for the logs when the issue happens, not now. You may find older logs in the `/var/log` directory, such as `/var/log/Xorg.1.log` as the previous one. But you really need to capture it at the time of the issue, or go back through the older logs to find the timeslot when it happened.

Comment: those logs are from just after the problem occurred (I was able to trigger it again after a reboot). By googling one of the error messages I managed to find this thread which seems to be related https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-gpu-idling-display-engine-timed-out-since-524-x-and-linux-6-1-5/242543

Answer (score 1):

As @Linus noted in the comments, this has been reported on the Nvidia forums by multiple users since the start of 2023 (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-gpu-idling-display-engine-timed-out-since-524-x-and-linux-6-1-5/242543/12). As of now, there is no fix available.